# In IE8,chrome the dropdown-list takes the same width as the dropbox whereas in IE9 the dropdown-list's width varies.How it can be fixed?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

```
 .inpTxtE
 {
  font: 11px verdana;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border-right: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
  border-top: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
  border-left: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #7F9DB9 1px solid;
  width:70%;
}
```

But when the width is given as 72% it with be same as other in IE9.But when it is open in chrome dropdown width is more than other Text boxes.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" CssClass="inpTxtE" >
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the code i used.How i will fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                    input, select {
                        width: 200px;
                        border: 1px solid #000;
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        height: 22px;
                        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                        box-sizing: border-box;
                    }
                    input {
                        text-indent: 4px;
                    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" value="ABC"><br>
            <select>
                <option>1234567</option>
                <option>121212121212121</option>
                <option>12121212121212121212</option>
            </select>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this code should work....I Hope. Do mark it as answered if it works. I tested it in jsfiddle and it works for me.

Comment: How to get the control of <asp:DropDownList> & <asp:TextBox> instead of input and select.

Comment: Border color is not appling in the dropdown.

Comment: normally in css we use input:not([type]), input[type="text"], select.....You can also Take a look at bootstrap docs and scroll down to the Selects section.    http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;IE=10; IE=9;" />
        <style type="text/css">
                input, select {
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="ABC"><br>
        <select>
            <option>1234567</option>
            <option>121212121212121</option>
            <option>12121212121212121212</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```